# Finding language designers and programmers

Tags: language-design, compiler-theory

I'd like to create a new and open sourced language.
Since it's really rare to find programmers that actually dealt with compiler theory I need some advice.
How would you make a person interested in your open source project?
How do you bring him to a position where he wants to contribute?
Is there a special place where I can find those pepole (except sourceforge.net)?

Comment: I'd actually be quite interested in this - I don't know very much about language design but its something I find very interesting and it would be great to have a try.
What sort of thing did you have in mind?

Comment: One way is to ask on stackoverflow IF someone is interested in that (I'm not sure if that is allowed though, you might ask that on meta). What kind of language do you want to build? E.g. building a new .net language is rather "easy" because you can output IL and the memory infrastructure and a framework are already available.

Comment: Basically I want javascript for desktop apps that compiles to native, static code.
I call it Proto.

Comment: Do you plan to use existing code for parsing? Do you plan to compile directly into machine code or assembler/C(++)? Should it be cross-plaform?

Comment: I might use V8 as the base and rewrite it to a compiler.
C++ compiles to assembler as far as I know so it's enough imo.
It should be completely cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be very hard to get people interested in your project. History has shown that 99% (at a conservative estimate) of new programming languages are only ever used by their designer. So if you do it, do it for love and don't expect much if any outside interest.

Comment: I am doing it for the love but I need some kind of mentor at the very least.
Are there any online sources for language design?

Comment: Note that if you want more answers, it's a good idea to wait a while before accepting. I usually give it 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to spend some time lurking on sites like, say, [Lambda The Ultimate](http://www.lambda-the-ultimate.org) and reading up on theory of programming languages, compiler design, etc. I've heard that **Essentials of Programming Languages** by Friedman et al is a good intro text for the former, while you can't go wrong with the "Dragon Book" for the latter (whose official title escapes me at the moment... by Aho et al though).

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Haskell (and its supporting community)
http://www.haskell.org/

I've used Haskell to model a small OO programming language in grad school and it seemed to be a common tool used in the Academia for designing programming language

Answer (score 0):

BTW, this doesn't answer your questions but these two Microsoft / Codeplx projects both sparked my interest as possible starting points for creating a new language:

- [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://www.codeplex.com/dlr)
- [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/)